# How to get rid of nested future in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've got some code in my play framework app that parses a JSON request and uses it to update a user's data. The problem is that I need to return a `Future[Result]`, but my `userDAO.update` function returns a `Future[Int]` so I have nested futures.

I've resorted to using `Await` which isn't very good. How can I rewrite this code to avoid the nested future?

```
def patchCurrentUser() = Action.async { request =>
Future {
  request.body.asJson
}.map {
  case Some(rawJson) => Json.fromJson[User](rawJson).map { newUser =>
    val currentUserId = 1

    logger.info(s"Retrieving users own profile for user ID $currentUserId")

    val futureResult: Future[Result] = userDAO.findById(currentUserId).flatMap {
      case Some(currentUser) =>
        val mergedUser = currentUser.copy(
          firstName = newUser.firstName        // ... and the other fields
        )

        userDAO.update(mergedUser).map(_ => Ok("OK"))
      case _ => Future { Status(404) }
    }

    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    // this is bad. How can I get rid of this?
    Await.result(futureResult, 1 seconds)
  }.getOrElse(Status(400))
  case _ => Status(400)
}
}
```

**Update**:

Sod's law: Just after posting this I worked it out:

```
Future {
  request.body.asJson
}.flatMap {
  case Some(rawJson) => Json.fromJson[User](rawJson).map { newUser =>
    val currentUserId = 1
    userDAO.findById(currentUserId).flatMap {
      case Some(currentUser) =>
        val updatedUser = currentUser.copy(
          firstName = newUser.firstName
        )

        userDAO.update(updatedUser).map(_ => Ok("OK"))
      case _ => Future { Status(404) }
    }
  }.getOrElse(Future(Status(400)))
  case _ => Future(Status(400))
}
```

But, is there a more elegant way? It seems like I'm peppering `Future()` around quite liberally which seems like a code smell.

Comment: Just avoid the `Future { request.body.asJson }`. This is going to be run in it's own thread anyway. Also, avoid `Future(Stauts(xx))`, because that is going to unnecessarily create an async computation. What you want is `Future.successful`

Comment: @rethab Thanks for the tip. I didn't know about `Future.successful`. But the `Future { request.body.asJson }` was so I could use the async action and return the `Future` associated with retrieving the user from the DB... (i.e. just to make the type checker happy)

Comment: I also discovered that play provides `body parsers` one of which will return a `400` if it can't parse the request to JSON. Do this with `Action.async(parse.json)` instead of just `Action.async`, and that means `request.body` will be a `JsValue`, which is one less `Future` to deal with.

Comment: Note that play will internally wrap your stuff in a future anyway if you don't use the async versions. So there's no penalty in using the non-async versions if there's nothing blocking in your actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

```
flatMap[A, B](f: A => Future[B])

map[A, B](f: A => B)
```

More elegant way is to use `for comprehension`

**Using For comprehension Code looks like this**

```
 for {
      jsonOpt <-  Future (request.body.asJson)
      result <- jsonOpt match {
        case Some(json) =>
          json.validate[User] match {
            case JsSuccess(newUser, _ ) =>
              for {
                currentUser <- userDAO.findById(1)
                _ <- userDAO.update(currentUser.copy(firstName = newUser.firstName))
              } yield Ok("ok")
            case JsError(_) => Future(Status(400))
          }
        case None => Future(Status(400))
      }
    } yield result
```

Comment: If mentioning a `for comprehension`, I believe it's worthwhile to show an example - to help the `OP`. Also, why is it cleaner to use this approach?

Comment: Yes please show an example. I tried to turn it into a for comprehension but couldn't work out how. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As @pamu said it might clear your code a bit if you would use a for comprehension.

Another interesting approach (and more pure in terms of Functional Programming) would be to use `monad transformers` (normally a type similar to `Future[Option[T]]` screams monad transformer).

You should take a look at libraries like [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) (and or scalaz). I'll try to give a small "pseudo code" example using cats (because I don't have play framework locally):

```
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

def convertJsonToUser(json: Json): Future[Option[User]] = Json.fromJson[User](json)
def convertBodyToJson(request: Request): Future[Option[Json]] = Future {request.body.asJson}
def updateUser(user: User): Future[HttpResult] = Future {
  // update user
  Ok("ok")
}

def myFunction: Future[HttpResult] = {
  val resultOpt: OptionT[Future, HttpResult] = for {
    json <- OptionT(convertBodyToJson(request))
    user <- OptionT(convertJsonToUser(json))
    result <- OptionT.lift(updateUser(user))
  } yield result
  result.getOrElseF(Future {Status(400)})
}
```

As you can see, in this case the monad transformers allow to treat a type like `Future[Option[T]]` as a single "short-circuiting" type (e.g. the for comprehension will stop if you have either a failed future, or a future containing a None).